# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, autocomplete

I have written a windows base program which works in a network .

First i had an autocomplete textbox which was reading the names from the databae and shows to the user according to the letter they have entered.

The program was working properly however it sometimes had that error

but

now i have added another autocomplete textbox reading from database, and now the first autocomplete works properly but when i want to fill the second textbox it shows this error and freezes.

The Interesting point is that the program works properly on the server and only shows this error on the client. 
even it doesnt have any error when i execute it on my laptop or the other laptops i made them a network with my laptop at home, it only has error on the client computer of the office.

please help me with solving this problem.

thank you

the full exception content is :

```
-----Exception Type Is : UnHandled
-----Exceptiotn Message is : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
-----Source that causes this error: System.Windows.Forms
-----StackTrace is : at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchM essageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoCompo nentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.Run MessageLoopInner(Int32 reason,ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.Run MessageLoop(Int32 reason,ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
at Project1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\ZY\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\Project1\Program.cs:line 25
```

my autocomplete code is:

```
private void txtkhrdsharh_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

            AutoCompleteStringCollection namecollection = new     AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            BLL objbll = new BLL();
            SqlDataReader rea = objbll.SelectSharhlistF(txtkhrdsharh.Text);
            if (rea.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (rea.Read())
                    namecollection.Add(rea["sharh"].ToString());
            }
            rea.Close();

            txtkhrdsharh.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            txtkhrdsharh.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txtkhrdsharh.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namecollection;
    }
```

Comment: Calling all psychic debuggers...

Comment: "It froze"? Either not sufficient hardware or you're lying.

Comment: Unhandled exception occurs, exception dialog appears so program freezes...pretty sure that's what is meant

Comment: The "Attempt to read or write protected memory" error typically occurs in native (i.e. unmanaged) code or in unsafe code when you're working with pointers. Are you calling unmanaged code somewhere? Are you using unsafe code/pointers? Does the exception stack trace give you any indication of where the error occurs?

Comment: as i said this error appears when i add another autocomplete textbox so it should be related to the autocomplete. I added the complete error to the main post . it says error occures in line 25 of program.cs :  Application.Run(new frm1());

Comment: Does the machine it fails on have the correct .NET runtime installed?

Comment: No, it installed correctly with no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem .
As Jim said it was related to my auto complete code that was sending request to server by every letter where user was entering . and the server was weak and was not able to answer this much requests.
I changed my code to the code bellow and the problem solved.
I put the code here: it may be useful for some one want to use autocomplete for first time (like me) :

```
               private void frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection namecollectionF = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        BLL objbll1 = new BLL();
        SqlDataReader dReader = objbll1.SelectNamelistF();
        if (dReader.HasRows == true)
        {
            while (dReader.Read())

                namecollectionF.Add(dReader["Name"].ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
        }
        dReader.Close();

        txtForooshande.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtForooshande.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        txtForooshande.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namecollectionF;
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very confusing. You're modifying the autocomplete settings whenever the text in the textbox changes. Why would you do that? Typically you'd set up the autocompletion when you create the textbox. As it stands, you're changing the settings every time the user presses a key on the textbox.

I'll grant that I don't know why (or even if) that would cause the program to crash, but it's likely to be a performance problem at least and possibly result in some very strange behavior.

I suspect that you want to revisit your implementation and make those autocomplete settings when the form is first displayed.

The exception is being thrown in the windows message handler--the message loop run by your application. It's not code you wrote, and it would likely be very difficult to see where the error occurs.

However, it would be very useful to determine *when* the error occurs. If you can load the program in the debugger and single-step that TextChanged event handler, you might be able to determine which line of code triggers the exception.

Comment: you were asked : However, it would be very useful to determine when the error occurs. The answer is when i enter the letter in first textbox it has no problem and shows all names in autocomplete , but when i enter letter into second autocomplete textbox the error apears

Comment: @PhoenixPhoenix: Maybe the problem is not in the handler at all. Does the error occur if you comment out the code in the TextChanged handler? Also, it will be impossible to provide much more help unless you load the program in the debugger and single-step the handler code so you can tell us what line of code triggers the exception.

Comment: and i didnt undrestand what is the problem with the autocomplete code ? the code should perform by every letter that user enters, for example for the name JOHN , first should search in database for names start with J , then search the names starts whith JO an so on. Is it wrong ?

Comment: The main problem is i dont receive that error on my laptop, so i can not test it. this error only produce on the end user machine. and it make the testing very difficult to me